# fetch record that is equal to 1 or 0 laravel eloqouent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using this one

```
$notification = notification::where('department', '=', 1)->get();
```

to fetch all records that has 'department' of 1 in my database (it works)

Now, I want to fetch also all records that neither has 'department' of 1 or 0, any ideas, help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `whereIn` or `whereNotIn` clauses?

```
$notification = notification::whereIn('department', [1, 2])->get();
```